# How to fix the following CSS error: Expected RBRACE

Tags: css, atom-editor

I have the following CSS code:

```
.text {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #E36A0C;
  background: white url(Project 1. Maths Website\Images\searchlogo.png) right center no-repeat;
}
```

when trying to save, I keep getting the following error:

Expected RBRACE at line 38, col 67

[image: screenshot of code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you have provided wrong path for the background image url.
Try with giving an valid URL, This may solve your problem.

background: white url(`**Project 1. Maths Website\Images\searchlogo.png**`) right center no-repeat;

try with

```
background: white url('../Images/searchlogo.png') right center no-repeat;
```

Comment: This solved my issue straight away. I appreciate your help so much, Lijo.